# Analogs of the paralleloram identity in higher degrees

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

I asked this two months ago in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226024/analogs-of-the-paralleloram-identity-in-higher-degrees), but nobody answered, so I hope it will be suitable here.

A *homogenious polynomial* of degree $k\in{\Bbb N}$ on a finite dimensional vector space $X$ over $\Bbb R$ is a polynomial $f:X\to{\Bbb R}$ satisfying the identity
$$
f(\lambda\cdot x)=\lambda^k\cdot f(x),\qquad x\in X,\quad \lambda\in{\Bbb R}
$$
It is known that the formulas 
$$
f(x)=\alpha(x,...,x),\qquad x\in X,
$$
$$
\alpha(x_1,...,x_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_k}...
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda_1} f(\lambda_1\cdot x_1+...+\lambda_k\cdot x_k)\Big|_{\lambda_i=0},\qquad x_i\in X,
$$
establish a bijection between homogenious polynomials $f:X\to{\Bbb R}$ of degree $k$ on $X$ and symmetric polylinear forms $\alpha:X^k\to{\Bbb R}$. (As far as I understand, the last formula here is called [polarization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_of_an_algebraic_form).)

In the special case, when $k=2$ we can, first, define homogenious polynomial as a *quadratic form*, i.e. a polynomial $f:X\to{\Bbb R}$ satisfying the *parallelogram identity*,
$$
\frac{f(x+y)+f(x-y)}{2}=f(x)+f(y),\qquad x,y\in X,
$$
and, second, replace the (analytic) polarisation formula by the purely algebraic formula
$$
\alpha(x,y)=\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)-f(y)}{2},\qquad x,y\in X.
$$

My question:

> What are the analogs of the last two identities in higher degrees (when $k>2$)?

In other words, which identities characterize homogenious polynomials $f$ of degrees 3, 4,..., instead of the homogenity condition, and which (algebraic) identities can be used for expressing $\alpha$ instead of the (analytic) polarization formula?